# String not space or null but what is it?

Tags: bash

I have a file named Try1.txt which contains the string "End Date   :   1/1/2014"
I have a file named Try2.txt which contains the string "End Date   :"
I have a bash script called myscript.sh which contains the following code:

```
$ myscript.sh Try1.txt
```

This works as expected.

```
$ myscript.sh Try2.txt
```

This does not work as expected.
I also tried comparing it to "" and " " and got the same result.
Why does it think the string is not null or empty?

```
END_DATE=$(grep "End Date" $1 | gawk -F":" '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g')

if [ -n "${END_DATE##+([[:space:]])}" ];
then
    echo "END_DATE is not null or space"
    printf "END_DATE: %b\n" "$END_DATE"
else
    echo "what is it then?"
    printf "END_DATE: %b\n" "$END_DATE"
fi

if [ -n "$END_DATE" ]
then
    echo "END_DATE is not null"
else
    echo "END_DATE is null"<br>
fi
```

Comment: `end_date=$(awk '/^End Date\s+:/{print $4}' $1)` would save you a lot of trouble and a few subprocesses

Comment: @Matt the awk code always returns null, so Try1 no longer works any more.

Comment: By the way bash-2.03$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 2.03.0(1)-release (i386-pc-cygwin32)
Copyright 1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Bash 2.03? That's from 14 years ago! I'm not really confident that version understands your regex substitution. What I posted works for me with input copy/pasted from your post, with just a `-z` or `-n` test, not that fancy substitution.

Answer (score 1):

try `if [ -z "$END_DATE" ]`

-z has to be used for NULL checks

Comment: There is no such thing like ``NULL`` in bash. Variable can be empty, variable can be unset, but there is no ``NULL``

Comment: Empty or unset is what I meant NULL.. did i code something NULL above? just for understanding I mentioned it. Thanks

Comment: It is misleading anyway.

Comment: May be just you! Time for a break!

Answer (score 1):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can do this:

```
if [[ ! $END_DATE ]]
```

This works because empty strings are falsy.

Please note that `[[ ]]` syntax is used, not `[ ]`. Read about the difference [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

### But! There is much easier way in your case:

```
endDate=$(grep -Pom 1 'End Date\s+:\s+\K.*' "$1")
if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then # $? is the return status of a previous command. Grep will return 0 if it found something, and 1 if nothing was found.
    echo "Date was found. Date=$endDate"
else
    echo 'Date was not found'
fi
```

This way you don't even need `sed` or `awk` or anything else.
I have also added '-m 1' to make sure that only one line is found. And the quotes around `"$1"` are essential.